# "ahead of" is NOT used with a particular time reference?

Tags: word-usage

Am I right that the phrase "ahead of" is NOT used with a particular time reference such as "ahead of 2 o'clock"?

Answer (score 1):

That is correct. "Ahead of time" is proper, but "ahead of" with a specific time is not typically used. One would instead say something like "before two o'clock".

Answer (score 0):

*Ahead of* essentially means, and is used in the sense of, 'before the time or position of.'

Now we can see why a point in time or space cannot be used with the phrase.